# Redirect Old PDF file to a new PDF file

Tags: seo, redirects, search-engines, pdf

I have 6 PDF files that have been updated and will use a different file name. All files are in one folder. Old PDFs have been indexed in the search engines.

I saw one solution but I think it only works if you have one PDF per folder which is not the case here.

http://www.henderson.cc/wp/tag/301-redirect/

How do I make the switch to the new files?

Comment: You wouldn't want to use a meta refresh as mentioned in that article. Google recommends against using them. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

Use a 301 redirect as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the old file is called, then change it to the new file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^old-file.pdf$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /new-file.pdf [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is this what you wanted?? ^old-file.xml$ instead of ^old-file.pdf$

Comment: Doesnt change the logic of what I ment, but yes, made a mistake :) Thanks.

Comment: I respect that. I just wanted to alert you to a mistake. We all make them! Cheers!!

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. Could it be because the file is not in root? The structure is like this: http://example.com/digital/2014/old.pdf (new.pdf is in the same folder)